# jQuery toggle on/off between multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I have quite a simple jQuery toggle working here: http://jsfiddle.net/yVa3U/1/ - but I can't work out how to get the active div to toggle off when the next div is clicked.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.answer').hide();

  $(".toggle").click(function(){

      $("div[rel='profile_" + $(this).attr("profile") + "']").toggle(400);
});

});​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add

```
$(".answer").not($(this).next()).hide(400);
```

before you call the `toggle()` function

**Side notes**

1. You could change the line `$("div[rel='profile_" +
   $(this).attr("profile") + "']").toggle(400);` to
   `$(this).next().toggle(400);`
2. Instead of using the attribute `profile` you should better use the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yVa3U/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to `hide` `all` the answers on click `except` the `current` answer, you can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yVa3U/8/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.answer').hide();
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        currentAnswerDiv = $("div[rel='profile_" + $(this).attr("profile") + "']");
        $('.answer').not(currentAnswerDiv).hide();
        currentAnswerDiv.toggle(400);
    });
});​
```

Comment: doesn't toggle the active answer if click on same toggle element twice

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next()`

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
       var $next=$(this).next().toggle(400)
      $('.answer').not($next).hide();  
});
```

It is better to hide your answer class with CSS rather than wait for ready event in javascript

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yVa3U/7/

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/next/